# Requiring entry in one of two channel fields?

Tags: custom-fields, channel, fields, entry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fieldtype for 2 dependant fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/848/fieldtype-for-2-dependant-fields)

I am wondering if its possible to have a relationship between two channel fields.  For example, lets say you have two text inputs: email and mobile_phone.  Is it possible to say at least one of these fields is required before successfully adding an entry?

Thanks!